# Clicar em opção no select e aparecer outros campos

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando fazer algo parecido com a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://jsfiddle.net/zbdvke2w/11/

Como faço para para os campos que estão em ICMS e ICMS ST com ng-if aparecerem apenas depois de clicar na opção  `10 - Tributada com Cobrança de ICMS por ST`?

Acontece que atualmente se eu clicar em qualquer opção do select da `Situação Tributaria` aparecem os campos para ICMS e ICMS ST, eu que fiz assim por não saber ainda filtrar pela opção, então se selecionar qualquer opção no select Situação Tributaria vai aparecer os campos, como fazer para aparecer somente depois que clicar na opção `10 - Tributada com Cobrança de ICMS por ST`?

Comment: Olhei por cima teu código, só o que precisa fazer é uma "condição" no teu `ng-show` ou `ng-if`, por exemplo: `ng-show="icms.situacao.value == 12"`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqd0ezhz/

Comment: Obrigada @PedroCamaraJunior `.value` não funcionou corretamente para mim troquei por `.id` e deu certo. Mas esta acontecendo algo curioso, quando clico em Tributação Normal -> 00 - Tributada Integralmente (por exemplo) aparece os Respectivos campos... em seguida vou no select Regime e escolho outro regime, o select situação tributaria desaparece mas não o conteudo ICMS e ICMS ST http://jsfiddle.net/zbdvke2w/13/